# rails: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out why I getting this error: "param is missing or the value is empty"

Here is my code:

```
class TodoodooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todos = Todoodoo.where(done: false)
    @completes = Todoodoo.where(done: true)
  end

  def new
    @todoo = Todoodoo.new
  end

  def create
    @todoo = Todoodoo.new(todo_params)

    if @todoo.save
      redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was created!"
    end
  end

  def update
    @todoo = Todoodoo.find(todo_params)

    if @todoo.update_attribute(:done, true)
      redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was marked as done!"
    else
      redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was unable to be marked as done!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @todoo = Todoodoo.find(todo_params)
    @todoo.destroy

    redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was deleted!"
  end

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todoodoo).permit(:name, :done)
  end

 end
```

As context I'm creating a very simple to-do app and I'm getting stuck when it tries to execute the "update" function.

Below is my view for the controller:

```
<h1> Check: Rule Your Day </h1>


<h2><u> To Do </u></h2>
<% @todos.all.each do |todo| %>
  <p>
     <strong><%= todo.name %></strong>
     <small><%= link_to "Mark as Done", todoodoo_path(todo), :method => :put %></small>
 </p>
<% end %>

<h2><u> Completed </u></h2>
<% @completes.all.each do |todo| %>
  <p>
    <%= todo.name %>
    <small><%= link_to "Remove", todo, :confirm => "Is it okay to remove this from the list?", :method => :delete %></small>
  </p>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Add a to-do item", new_todoodoo_path %></p>
```

My todoodoo model has nothing in the file. I created it executing the following "rails g model todoodoo name: string done: boolean" Can it be a problem with my model?

Thanks for helping. Everything else seems to be working fine. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: what is `t` in 4th line from the end?

Comment: I think that was supposed be "todo"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not updating or creating a record based on direct user input, you don't have to use strong parameters. In a `find` call you *never* have to use strong parameters. It's only meant for updating and creating records.

In other words, you shouldn't do:

```
Todoodoo.find(todo_params)
```

but:

```
Todoodoo.find(params[:id])
```

Your `update` action should look like this:

```
def update
  @todoo = Todoodoo.find(params[:id])

  if @todoo.update_attribute(:done, true)
    redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was marked as done!"
  else
    redirect_to todoodoo_index_path, :notice => "Your To-Do item was unable to be marked as done!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `update` method, change `@todoo = Todoodoo.find(todo_params)` to `@todoo = Todoodoo.find(params[:id])`. Strong parameters (`todo_params`) are used in assignment, they're not designed to be used for finding records.

Comment: Thanks Inkling! Really like your explanation of the issue and solution, makes perfect sense